# Разделение функционала триггеров

Tags: sql, sql-server

Начал изучать триггеры более детально и столкнулся с проблемой о нагромождении функциональности триггеров .

Начнем , у нас есть стандартный код создания таблиц :

```
Create table test_one 
(
  Id int primary key not null identity,
  test_field1 varchar(30)
);
go
Create table test_two
(
 Id int primary key not null identity,
 test_field2 varchar(30)
)
go
Create table test_three
(
 Id int primary key not null identity,
 test_field3 varchar(30)
);
```

И соответственно есть код для создания триггеров (здесь будет два варианта) :

**А)** Создаем триггер с двумя операторами INSERT :

```
create trigger trigger_two_insert_methods
on test_one
for insert
as 
  insert into test_two (test_field2) select test_field1 from test_one
  insert into test_three(test_field3) select test_field1 from test_one
go
```

**B)** Создаем 2 отдельных от друг друга триггера :

*Первый :*

```
create trigger trigger_1
on test_one
for insert
as 
  insert into test_two (test_field2) select test_field1 from test_one
go
```

*Второй :*

```
create trigger trigger_2
on test_one
for insert
as 
  insert into test_three (test_field3) select test_field1 from test_one
go
```

Теперь сам **вопрос**. В общем ,я понимаю что в триггеры не стоит писать слишком много инструкций , **НО** стоит ли разделять функционал таких триггеров на несколько поменьше (если стоит ,то насколько большой выигрыш мы получим по скорости после разделения)

**И** хотелось бы узнать в каком случае нам действительно стоит разделять один триггер на несколько (например когда у нас только 2-3 INSERT-оператора в одном триггере - оставить так как есть или лучше разделить ?)

Заранее,спасибо!

Comment: Думаю разделение сделано только для логической работы с триггерами как с отдельными модулями кода, что бы не мешать все в одну кучу. Очень сильно сомневаюсь, что разделение повысит производительность, скорее уж понизит

Comment: @Mike Откопал статейку по этой теме - http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/SQL-Server-trigger-example-One-trigger-vs-two-for-the-same-logic

И тут вычитал что если триггер действительно большой,то лучше разделить ,так как тогда меньшие "куски" ,(если так можно выразится)  при вызове отдельных триггеров ,памяти используются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел  статейку по этой теме - http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/SQL-Server-trigger-example-One-trigger-vs-two-for-the-same-logic
 И тут прочитал что если триггер действительно большой,то его лучше разделить ,чтобы задействовать меньше памяти при его вызове